# div cannot animate bottom side and goes outside from window screen from every side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is working fine with left,right and top animate div move from left side, right side and top side but it is not working with bottom side div can not move bottom. and also when i press key more than ten time or more quikly it goes outside from my window screen from every side and if i press key after one animation finish it can not goes out side.

my html code:

```
<body>
  <div class="block"></div>
</body>
```

my css code:

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #abc;
  left: 50px;
  top:50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

my jquery code:

```
$(window).load(function(e) {
    $("body").keydown(function(e) {
    var width1 = $(window).width();
    var heigth1 = $(window).height();
    if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
        if (parseInt($('.block').css('left')) >= 50) {     
            $('.block').animate({left: '-=50'},"slow");
        }
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
        if (parseInt($('.block').css('left')) <= (width1 - 150)){     
            $(".block").animate({left: "+=50px"},'slow');
        }
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 40){ // bottom
        if (parseInt($('.block').css('top')) <= (height1 - 150)) { 
            $(".block").animate({'top':'+=50px'},'slow');
        }
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 38){ // top
        if (parseInt($('.block').css('top')) >= 50) {     
            $(".block").animate({'top':'-=50px'},'slow');
        }
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Please turn this ugly "if else if else ..." into a switch `:D`

Comment: what is the benefit with switch case code was the same switch case is same work as if else condition.

Comment: To me and many people, switch is easier to read `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is my example, hope i help you :)

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/XBHkJ/1/)

```
:)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I have a bad English so I can not explain

Comment: @AramMkrtchyan it's working but not properly it's work it is also goes outside some part not a  full div. but it's ok for now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Typo!

```
var heigth1 = $(window).height();
```

should be

```
var height1 = $(window).height();
```

Comment: yes you are right that was my mistake thanks it solve my one problem but cannot other

Comment: When developing in JS, always have the console tab in developer tools open. This will immediately alert you to any syntax errors.